# Not able to restart MongoDB container

Tags: mongodb, docker

We are running MongoDB as docker container and all of sudden it become unresponsive. We had tried to restart container but it didnt. The docker restart command was success but if we check the service it didnt restarted. We are not able to connect to DB from our Mongo client too.

After full VM restart the problem got solved. I would like to know if anyone has faced this issue and got any solution for it.

Here is the details my docker:

Docker version 19.03.12
Mongo 4.0

Comment: Well, check the MongoDB logs.

Comment: **2021-12-06T22:39:04.730+0000 ** I COMMAND  [PeriodicTaskRunner] task: DBConnectionPool-cleaner took: 16748ms
**2021-12-07T03:33:34.550+0000 ** I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'

Comment: Here is the log but no info about error we found in the log. Here is the restart log.

2021-12-07T03:33:34.641+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=567e75e5e0bd
2021-12-07T03:33:34.641+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.20

Comment: You don't mention how you start the container in the first place and how you tried to restart it. Also the two lines of the log don't tell anything without a comment. It's definitely not "the log". Add this information to the question itself.

Comment: ok. Docker started using docker-compose file and restart was done using command 'docker restart <contianer-id>'.

## Mongo DB
version: '3.7'

services:
  my_mongo:
    container_name: my_mongo
    image: mongo:4.0
    env_file:
      - /opt/ncms/.env.mongodb
    volumes:
      - /opt/ncms/mongo_init_scripts/charge/init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.js
      - /opt/ncms/mongo_db/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - "host-port:27017"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - my_network

## Create network
networks:
  my_network:

Comment: I am seeing these logs in container logs. Do you recommend any other logs verify ?

Comment: Actually /var/log/mongodb.log (or alike). What restart policy are you using? Did you have to run docker-compose after restarting the VM? I'm asking in order to know whether the container has been rebuilt when it worked again (which it is not for docker restart). That being said, I suppose you simply ran out of hard disk space.

Comment: I have just rebooted the VM and container got restarted by itself. We didnt ran docker-compose after restart of VM. I will check mongodb.log file in container.  Before restarting VM I have verified those diskspace, memory everything was fine and also I was able to do SSH to host.